# Rendering an ERB template with a presenter

Tags: ruby, erb

I am trying to render a `.txt.erb` file which uses a presenter to display values. The following code is inside `ConfigurationWorker` which is perfomed by resque:

```
@configuration = Configuration.first
@view = Rails.root.join 'lib', 'templates', 'config.txt.erb' 
ERB.new(File.read(@view)).result(binding)
```

The `config.txt.erb` looks like this (shortened for simplicity):

```
<% present @configuration do |presenter| %>
  Name <%= presenter.name %>
<% end %>
```

Whereas `present` is provided by `ApplicationHelper` and `ConfigurationPresenter`.

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def present(object, klass = nil)
    klass ||= "#{object.class}Presenter".constantize
    presenter = klass.new(object, self)

    yield presenter if block_given?
    return presenter
  end
end

class ConfigurationPresenter < ApplicationPresenter
  presents :configuration
  delegate :name, :configuration

  # Presenter methods omitted
end

class ApplicationPresenter
  def initialize(object, template)
    @object = object
    @template = template
  end

  def self.presents(name)
    define_method(name) do
      @object
    end
  end

  def method_missing(*args, &block)
    @template.send(*args, &block)
  end
end
```

However, this results in `NoMethodError: undefined method present for ConfigurationWorker:Class`.

I also tried other approaches, like

```
@configuration = Configuration.first
renderer = ApplicationController.view_context_class.new
renderer.render :file => Rails.root.join('lib', 'templates', 'config.txt.erb')
```

which results in `ActionView::Template::Error: uninitialized constant NilClassPresenter`.

What is the proper way to make both the helper and the presenter available and pass in the variables?

Comment: I just ran into a very similar problem. How did you resolve it?